# Handling Null Values in Lambda Expression

Tags: java, string, lambda, nullpointerexception, null

I am trying to iterate `List` of `Map` using lambda expression and while iterating I have to set the values in one POJO using field setter method. The problem comes when there are `null` values in `List` of `Map` (in particular map field `null` should be handled). I tried so many things to handle `NullPointerException`.

```
Employee employee = new Employee();

employee.setEmployeeName(result.getOrDefault("employeeName", "").toString());

employee.setEmployeeName(!StringUtils.isEmpty(result.get("employeeName").toString()) ? result.get("employeeName").toString() : " "); 
// when i am using this solution it is not giving null pointer exception 
// but if the value is null then it is returning "null" value it means 
// null as a string which shouldn't be the expected output. 

employee.setEmployeeName(String.valueOf(result.get("employeeName").equals("null") ? "" : result.get("employeeName")));

List<Map<String,Object>> r1 = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
    response.forEach(result -> { 
        employee.setEmployeeName(result.getOrDefault("employeeName", "").toString());

    })
```

Comment: `StringUtils.isEmpty` does not return a null pointer exception as per its documentation.

Comment: Check if your "result" in your lambda is null. Use a debugger. You can make your code a bit more step-by-step to be able to analyse every little step happening, every variable etc. You can also use Optionals to avoid NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: Is this still a problem? It could help to clarify your code, what is `response` or is that the same as `r1`. Which value is `null` and what is the stacktrace of the `NullPointerException` which you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved i used Optional like below.

```
Optional.ofNullable(result.get("employeeName")).orElse(" ").toString()
```